# Google fit api can't read steps recorder by the official app

Tags: google-fit

I recently updated to lollipop, I'm not sure if that did but recently I noticed my apps read request can't get the steps recorded by the official google fit app but I can see steps recorded by my app as misc steps.  Has anyone come across this or know if there's a special way to access google fits official data.

Answer (score 0):

Check method

```
public abstract PendingResult<DailyTotalResult> readDailyTotal (GoogleApiClient client, DataType dataType)
```

It gets daily step count.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/HistoryApi.html